# Bootstrap 3: Mobile view multiple select "0 elements selected"

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap (v3.3.7) multiple select for a form. This is how it looks like on mobile

[image]

No matter how many elements I select it will always say 0. Why is this? There are no problems when the form is submitted, this is an UI issue. Here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <label for="example" class="label-heading"><?php echo $label ?></label>
   </div>     

   <div class="col-md-8 ui-front" style="z-index: auto;">
      <select name="example" multiple class="form-control" id="example" placeholder="Multiselect">
         <?php foreach($team->result() as $r) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $r->ID ?>"><?php echo $r->first_name . ' ' . $r->last_name ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
      <span class="help-block">Help text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the eventlistener that should handle updating the shown value when a user selects something?

Comment: Have you try to see if you have any console error? have you try to print first_name and last_name for see if all is ok?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I don't see any console errores and yes, PHP code is fine

Comment: @StevenKuipers I'm not sure if I understand. All the event listeners in console are from bootstrap and jQuery but I don't have any idea what to look for there. I did not add any other code myself, its all vanilla bootstrap 3.

Comment: where is your initialization of `new vanillaSelectBox("#example")`

Comment: whats on your event listener? Please check value of events.

Comment: You are writing in php, that means when the form is submitted the page is refreshing. Do you run php through ajax to prevent default refresh?

Answer (score 0):

#### Could you try using the foreach loop as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dynamically Generate Select Dropdowns</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
                <?php
                    // A sample product array
                    $products = array("Mobile", "Laptop", "Tablet", "Camera");
        
                    // Iterating through the product array
                    foreach($products as $item){
                    ?>
                         <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>">
                             <?php echo $item; ?>
                         </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Code Source: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com )